# Leverage Browser caching issue in codeigniter php website

Tags: javascript

Here i got the tracking code for google analytics which i need to add in online server to get the tracking of my website.
After adding this code i am getting the error as leverage broser caching because there is a online javascript link.

Here is the code for that:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-10456788-7', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Is there any process to remove leverage browser caching issue problem

.htaccess:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
 ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
 </IfModule>
```

### EXPIRES CACHING

Comment: you have to change your htaccess

Comment: @AnandPandey i have updated the code with htaccess file which i have written

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is also some configurations for various web server [see](https://github.com/hyipscript/server-configs) here.

```
# Enable Compression
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>

# Leverage Browser Caching
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
  ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|swf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public"
  </filesmatch>
  <filesmatch "\.(html|htm)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesmatch>
  <filesmatch "\.(pdf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
  </filesmatch>
  <filesmatch "\.(js)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, private"
  </filesmatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: check your site on gtmetrix

Comment: https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours) getting the same after as well

Comment: Downloaded the analytics file and uploaded to my web server it got fixed

Comment: glad it helps :)

Comment: Do you any idea how to remove render blocking javascript files

Comment: Sorry about that but i dont know

Answer (score 0):

Leverage Browser caching google-analytics

**Step 1** 
Create Cron php : example 1 week 
Duplicate analytics.js from google to your local js folder

**Example** :
//php code start

```
    <?php
    $ft=fopen("js/analytics.js", "w");
    $fs=fopen("https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js", "r");
    if ($fs==NULL)
    {
    exit(0);
   }
    if ($ft==NULL)
    {
    fclose ($fs);
    exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
    while ($ch=fgets($fs))
    fputs($ft, $ch);
    fclose ($fs);
   fclose ($ft);
}
?>
```

//php code end

**step 2 :**
replace your google code

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
   (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
   m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=true;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
   })(window,document,'script','js/analytics.js','ga');

   ga('create', 'UA-10456788-7', 'auto');
   ga('send', 'pageview');    
</script>
```

i have used this solution for [my website](https://myreservationsystem.com/) working fine. and google PageSpeed up to 97%